# DAX - Measure count active products

Tags: ssas, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

Tried a lot but didn't get any expected result.

I need a DAX measure which shows me the second result:

Based on my 2 tables, I need to know how many products is active if they appear in the second table - then 1, else 0

```
Product1
A
B
C
D
E
F


Product2
A
J
K
A
B
J
F
F
F
```

The result should be:

```
Product Measure
A   1
B   1
C   0
D   0
E   0
F   1
```

Count: 3

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- In the data model view, make a relationship between Product1 table and Product2 table... this should load by default as a one to many relationship
- Make a new table in Power BI or a pivot table in Excel.  Put Products column from Products1 table on rows
- Write a new measure as follows and drop it into your table

```html
Measure Name = 
  IF(
    COUNTROWS(Product2) > 0, 1, 0
  )
```

Hopefully something like that works for you.

Jake